# Arduino - Light is staying on for more than expected duration

Tags: arduino

Code is suppose to Light the inbuit-LED at Pin 13 whenever Pin 5 is High, however i have encountered couple of problem.

1. While measuring Voltage though Digital Meter - one pin at arduino GND and other at 1,2,3,4. They are showing some non-zero values. Earlier triggering Pin was 4 and light was staying on all the time.
2. When Pin 5 is high (by connecting 5V Pin from Arduino to Pin 5) it lights the LED as it should, but if Pin 5 stays high for more than 1/2 second, light stays high for more than 0.5 second even after the Pin 5 is disconnected from 5V Pin.

```
int buttonState = LOW;
int light = 13;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  pinMode(gateopen,INPUT);
  pinMode(light, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  buttonState = digitalRead(gateopen);
  if (buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(light, HIGH);
  } 
  else 
  {
    digitalWrite(light, LOW);
  }
  //delayMicroseconds(500);
}
```

Comment: the input pin is floating. add a pull down resistor

Answer (score 1):

1. As suggested earlier, use a pull down resistor. Or change your circuit to active low and use INPUT_PULLUP.
2. I believe you're using delayMicroSeconds, which means the led is just blinking waaay too fast for your eyes. If you want 'half a second' as you hinted on your query, you would be using delay(500) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You are experiencing electrical noise, just like Juraj said, just put a 220 Ohm pull down resistor